# how do i can use @ symbol in sqlquery

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
delimiter $$
    CREATE TABLE `users` (
      `u_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `ufirstname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
      `ulastname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `pswd` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `confirmpswd` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `mobileno` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`u_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

---

```
select u_id,ufirstname,mobileno whrer email=test@gmail.com
```

**and i am getting an error:**

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where' at line 1

please help me

Comment: Pretty much the same way you would use most other symbols...

Comment: You have more than `how to use @` problem here, Question aside, load of errors in the answers to this one amazes me.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing your FROM clause, you incorrectly spelled where and you didn't surround your string in quotes:

```
SELECT u_id, ufirstname, mobileno 
FROM users 
WHERE email = 'test@gmail.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
select u_id,ufirstname,mobileno from users where email='test@gmail.com'
```

You need to quote the string value

Comment: Not me downvoting, but a `FROM` clause is missing too.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson yeah missed that. Updated

Answer (score 0):

put it in quotes as a String is supposed to

```
SELECT u_id, ufirstname, mobileno FROM users WHERE email = 'test@gmail.com'
```

Comment: FROM statement is missing here?!